# Given two lists(A,B) with same length, How can I find the index(i) which makes the max(sum(A[:i],B[i:]),sum(A[i:],B[:i])) smallest?

Tags: python-3.6

I am working on an online challenge problem, and I can solve this problem with brute force, but when the length became very large, the runtime is significantly increased, I believe there must be a better algorithm to solve this problem, but it is just out of my hand. I appreciate any brilliant ideas.

Comment: Please add the code that you have written so far. It is easier to give suggestions after seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use `numpy`, by using `numpy.cumsum` method you can find store `sum(A[:i])`, `sum(A[i:])`, `sum(B[:i])`, and `sum(B[i:])` values in four different arrays as follows

```py
import numpy as np


A = []  # Array A
B = []  # Array B
A_start_to_i = np.cumsum(A)  # A_start_to_i[i] = sum(A[:i])
A.reverse()  # Reverse the order
A_i_to_end = np.cumsum(A)  # A_i_to_end[i] = sum(A[i:])
B_start_to_i = np.cumsum(B)  # B_start_to_i[i] = sum(B[:i])
B.reverse()  # Reverse the order
B_i_to_end = np.cumsum(B)  # B_i_to_end = sum(B[i:])
```

Now all you need to do is to create `sum(A[:i], B[i:])` and `sum(B[:i], A[i:])` and find the index with the minimum element.

```py
first_array = A_start_to_i + B_i_to_end  # first_array[i] = sum(A[:i], B[i:])
second_array = A_i_to_end + B_start_to_i  # second_array[i] = sum(B[:i], A[i:])

# Find which array has the minimum element
idx = np.argmin([min(first_array), min(second_array)])
if idx == 0:
   # First array has the minimum element
   i = np.argmin(first_array)
else:
   # Second array has the minimum element
   i = np.argmin(second_array)
```